# For TSP, how does Held–Karp algorithm reduce the time complexity from Brute-force's O(n!) to O(2^n*n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman

I have hard time to grasp the key idea of Held-Karp algorithm, how does it reduce the time-complexity?
Is it because it uses Dynamic programming so that time is saved by getting the intermediate result from the cache or because it removes some paths earlier in the calculation?

Also, is it possible to use 2 dimension table to show the calculation for
a simple TSP problem(3 or 4 cities)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dynamic programming procedure of the Held–Karp algorithm takes advantage of the following property of the TSP problem: *Every subpath of a path of minimum distance is itself of minimum distance.*

So essentially, instead of checking all solutions in a naive "top-down", brute force approach (of every possible permutation), we instead use a "bottom-up" approach where all the intermediate information required to solve the problem is developed once **and once only**. The initial step is the very smallest subpath. Every time we move up to solve a larger subpath, we are able to look up the solutions to all the smaller subpath problems which have already been computed. The time savings come because all of the smaller subproblems have already been solved and these savings compound exponentially (at each greater subpath level). But no "paths are removed" from the calculations–at the end of the procedure all of the subproblems will have been solved. The obvious drawback is that a very large memory size may be required to store all the intermediate results.

In summary, the time savings of the Held–Karp algorithm follow from the fact that it *never* duplicates solving the solution to any subset (combination) of the cities. But the brute force approach will recompute the solution to any given subset combination many times (albeit not necessarily in consecutive order within a given overall set permutation).

Wikipedia contains a 2D distance matrix example and pseudocode [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Held%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm#Example.5B4.5D).

Comment: But are there any Dynamic Programming algorithm do remove some sub-problems in the early stage? Any example?

Comment: Dynamic programming generally does not omit subproblems, but relies primarily on memoization. In comparison, a greedy algorithm treats the solution as some sequence of steps and picks the locally optimal choice at each step ("skips subproblems")--but this does not guarantee an optimal solution. However, some greedy algorithms (such as Kruskal's or Prim's for minimum spanning trees) are proven to lead to the optimal solution. A dynamic programming algorithm does not preclude it from possibly skipping some subproblems.

Comment: An example of an algorithm that both incorporates memoization and sub-problem omission could be a chess search. The search might regularly encounter transpositions of known endgames or openings (memoization) and still often use heuristics to skip evaluation of less promising candidate moves (skipping subproblems) in order to produce the next move in a reasonable amount of time.